# Calculating optimality gap when denominator goes to zero

Tags: optimality-gap

Using an optimality gap formula that calculates an average over large sets of instances is a common practice to assess the efficiency of an algorithm. The widely-used formula employed by CPLEX is: |bestbound - bestinteger| / (epsilon + |bestinteger|). However, a problem arises when the denominator approaches zero while the difference between the upper and lower bounds is small, causing the optimality gap to approach infinity. To address this issue and gain a better interpretation of results with an average across all instances, I propose setting epsilon to one. This adjustment would not significantly alter the optimality gap for instances where the best integer is greater than one, as its effect would be negligible. However, it would eliminate instances with an optimality gap percentage of 4000% or higher, replacing them with a value of at least 400. Considering the scale of large instances, this approach would mitigate the impact of such extreme values.

I'm not aware of any specific instances in the literature where epsilon with a value of "1" has been used extensively.

Could you please suggest any references or alternative solutions to my problem?

Comment: Something like is used in https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver. (minlp_gap_tol). Another simple approach: provide both an absolute and a relative gap tolerance.

Comment: Thanks, Erwin, still the formula and also the denominator are very different from what we commonly use in OR.

Comment: I would have some concerns with this. One is that the best integer value need not be an integer, since it is the objective value and not the variable value(s). So you might be looking at $(1 - 0.01)/(1 + 0.01) \approx 1,$ which suggests the bound is about twice the best integer value when it actually is 100x larger.

Comment: Indeed, I am currently engaged in the development of benchmark algorithms, and fortunately, I haven't encountered the issue you just mentioned within the solutions generated by these algorithms (I consider myself fortunate in this regard). Nonetheless, the presence of a zero denominator significantly undermines the quality of my results, particularly when dealing with extensive datasets. In some cases, this situation can lead to an alarming percentage increase, reaching as high as 4,000-5,000%.  I am stuck with explanations of these types of instances ...

Comment: I think I might have also found another supporting idea, suppose the objective function is to maximize x, now I add a constant and I maximize 1+x; so the denominator for this problem changes to 1 + |bestinteger| without using the epsilon idea, do you think this might be acceptable? The solution to the problem has not changed, still, I can have a better interpretation of my benchmarks.

Comment: Same problem, only worse. Take my previous example. Your gap would now be $(2-1.01)/1.01<1,$ while (in terms of the original objective) 1 is *much* bigger in percentage terms than 0.01. So you would be significantly understating the gap.

Comment: Suppose I have two algorithms for solving a maximization problem. With the first algorithm, I obtained a value of 0.01 for the best integer solution, similar to your result, with an optimality gap of 9900 (UB=1). On the other hand, the second algorithm produced a best integer solution of -1, along with an optimality gap of 200%. While I am aware that the first algorithm is performing better, these optimality gaps can be misleading and falsely suggest that the first algorithm is inadequate. Let's disregard the gap and focus on the superior performance of the first algorithm. But how?